# cfc function not receiving arguments when called from javascript via cfajaxproxy

Tags: javascript, ajax, parameters, coldfusion

I started getting this problem when I installed ColdFusion 2016 Update 4.

HTML:

```
<input type='button' name='btn' value='Click me' onclick='proxyFunc();'>
```

Proxy:

```
<cfajaxproxy cfc='proxy' jsClassName="jsProxyClass" >
```

Javascript:

```
proxyFunc = function () {
  var proxyObj = new jsProxyClass();
  proxyObj.setHTTPMethod("post");   
  proxyObj.setCallbackHandler (function (result) {
      console.log(result);
  });
  proxyObj.func('X');
}
```

CFC:

```
<cffunction name='func' access='remote' returntype='string' >
  <cfargument name='arg' type='string' required='false' >

  <cfreturn 'What is my arg? ' & arguments.arg>
</cffunction>
```

I set a breakpoint on  in my cfc and found that arguments.arg is blank
and I have form.argumentcollection = {"arg":"X"}

If I change setHTTPMethod from "post" to "get", arguments.arg = "X", as I would expect.

I have a lot of code that has been working fine before this CF update, and now it's all broken :(

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you do `proxyObj.func({'arg':'X'});`? Either way, CF's JS/AJAX stuff is always asking for trouble. If it works in Update 3 and changed in Update 4, it's probably a bug. Consider reporting it to Adobe.

Comment: When the line `proxyObj.setHTTPMethod("post");` is commented out, it works as it should; but uses a `GET` request.

Comment: @Alex I tried `proxyObj.func({'arg':'X'});` and arguments.arg is still blank, but form.argumentcollection = {"arg":{"arg":"X"}}  

I will go ahead and report to Adobe.

Comment: At a glance, the issue appears related to https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4197186 which is marked as Fixed in CF2016 Update 4.

Answer (score 4):

I found this patch that Adobe posted https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/cf-4198589 , and it worked for me.